# Replace spaces in a string with comma

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am trying to replace the spaces in a string by comma. The string looks like this

```
'1529954897.543 GET 200 173481 174274 "https://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/67.0.3391.0 Safari/537.36" "-" 1 0'
```

Now the issue here is, when i replace all the spaces, it also replaces the spaces in the substring "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/67.0.3391.0 Safari/537.36".

Is there a way I can not replace the spaces in a string inside a string?

Output i am expecting is this

```
'1529954897.543,GET,200,173481,174274,"https://www.facebook.com/","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/67.0.3391.0 Safari/537.36","-",1,0'
```

Comment: Yeah I know, and I did

Comment: I this is what I think it is then the url and user agent strings should contain `+` instead of spaces.

Comment: Did you say something about tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some `split` / `join` logic to only replace the whitespaces outside of ".." :

```js
const input = '1529954897.543 GET 200 173481 174274 "https://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/67.0.3391.0 Safari/537.36" "-" 1 0'

let result = input.split(`"`)
  .map((part, i) => i % 2 ?
    part :
    part.split(" ").join(",")
  ).join(`"`)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @getOffMyLawn thanks for snippeting :) (by the way, you were the third to do that with my answers today ..)

Comment: NP :) I am at work board and all... Need something to do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it character by character. Here is a naive implementation:

```js
function parsestr(str) {
  var tokens = [], i, ch, token = "", in_quote = false;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (ch === '"') {
      in_quote = !in_quote;
    } else if (ch === ' ' && in_quote === false) {
      tokens.push(token);
      token = "";
    } else {
      token += ch;
    }
  }
  if (token) {
    tokens.push(token);
  }
  return tokens;
}
var str = '1529954897.543 GET 200 173481 174274 "https://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/67.0.3391.0 Safari/537.36" "-" 1 0'
console.log(parsestr(str));
```